How do you access a computer system?
One of the things that I come across frequently and am unsure the "correct" way to describe is when I am talking about logging in to a computer system.
Do you:

log in to
login to
log into

If you want to get really wild you might even login into?

@Fe2O3 yes sorry didn't see that one.
